# kafka producer with integer value, IntegerSerializer is not working?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to create a **producer** who sends a message with **integer value**
I already configured the value type by this way:

```
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
```

But when I check localhost:3030 (Kafka Development Environment docker container powered by Landoop), the value is somethings like **\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001**

Can somebody give me some hints ? Thank you

Comment: I think i got the answer, I want to mark it for the other beginers: 

1. message value => Must be type bytes, or be serializable to bytes via configured **value_serializer**. 
2. In the topic, it shows like in the format 'bytes', if you want to see the real data, you should use a consumer configured **value_deserializer**  with same type of serializer

Comment: to be clear ... everything is just bytes :-) I think that the Landoop UI (I have never used it) is just using a String deserializer as Tom said.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like the integer 1 has been serialized using the IntegerSerializer (i.e. 4 bytes, network byte order), but has been deserialized as if it were a String in UTF-8 or similar 8 bit encoding (i.e. those 4 bytes are treated as codepoints, the first 3 being null, and the last one being 1). So when you say "I check", how are you checking? Specifically are you deserializing the bytes as an integer, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for reply, "i check" means that I just check the bytes, not deserializing them, that's why I was confused, why it is  \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001 instead of 1, I already made a comment of this misunderstanding.